# Help me to create a join based query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, join

The Join I have implemented is a basic one, but I can't figure out the issue in my query.
Can you help me to figure out where I have made a mistake?

Here is the scenario:

I have the following tables

[image]

and I am writing this query in T-SQL

```
Select 
   f._id, f.createdby, f.fullname, 
   f.topictitle, f.topicdate, f.status,
   f.totalviews, count(fr._id) as totalResponses 
from     
forumresponse as fr
RIGHT OUTER Join forum as f ON f._id = fr.forumId
where f.categoryId= @categoryId  
group by f._id, f.createdby, f.fullname, f.topictitle, 
         f.topicdate, f.status, f.totalviews
order by _id desc
```

But everytime I am getting same list of forums for any category.

I am trying to fetch the forum and its details which belongs to a particualr category only.
But whatever the category I am passing I'm getting same list of forum.

Comment: @Oded i have eddited my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` - use a regular `INNER JOIN`.

Using the outer join ensures *all* records from the right table (forum) will be returned, whether there is a matching one from the left table or not.

Comment: @Adam - It can take some time to understand the different JOIN types and how they operate.